# NGINX SSL Timeout

Tags: ssl, nginx

Runnning NGINX SSL and the browser continues to timeout.

Here is my NGINX conf file:

```
worker_processes  4;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    use epoll;
}

http {
    proxy_next_upstream error;
    charset utf-8;
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    keepalive_requests 0;
    proxy_read_timeout 200;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml
               application/x-javascript application/xml
               application/atom+xml text/javascript;
    server{
            ### WEB Address ###
        server_name mydomain.com;


            ### SSL log files ###
            access_log /var/log/nginx/ssl-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/ssl-error.log;
    listen 443;

            ### SSL Certificates ###
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/unified.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl.key;
    keepalive_timeout    60;

            ### PROXY TO TORNADO ###
            location / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8889;
        }
  }
}
```

The SSL access log and error log is blank.

I've tried restarting NGINX a couple of times. As a side note commenting out SSL and setting listen to 80 works for non-SSL connections.

Any help would be great?

Answer (score 76):

Maybe 443 port is closed on your server? Check this with http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Comment: I never though that this is going to be the problem you don't know how much happiness you brought to me.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks, helped me too :) with Let's Encrypt certificate.

Comment: Mate..you saved me :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, I checked and my port 443 is closed. How did you opened it to solved this?

Comment: I had the porn open from inside `lightsail` but had to open it from `console` as well

Answer (score 10):

I agree with Klen´s answer, and I would add more.

First, go and check that your port 443 is open in http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

If it´s closed, go to your aws console, select your instance and go to description -> security groups -> launch_wizard-1

[image]

Then click on edit -> Add Rule

Select HTTPS from the options and you should see this

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There are several things to check out

#1: Check if https is allowed in your ubuntu server

```
sudo ufw allow https && sudo ufw enable
```

#2: Check if port `443` is opened

Answer (score 0):

First i checked what is listening on port 443 by this command:

```
lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -P
```

I saw nginx which was correct
Then i checked whether the 443 is opened by the tool mentioned by klen (http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/)
Port 443 was closed so I had to run

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

to open port 443