# Application stops after configuring nginx (docker) for https

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx

I have followed this tutorial for deploying docker containers on AWS EC2 instance:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-a-containerized-node-js-application-with-nginx-let-s-encrypt-and-docker-compose

and after reaching step 5 (where nginx is configured for HTTPS), the application just stops working. Here's my application: [www.alphadevop.co](http://www.alphadevop.co)

Here’s my nginx configuration:
https://github.com/cyrilcabo/alphadevelopment/blob/master/nginx-conf/nginx.conf

And here’s my docker-compose.yml:
https://github.com/cyrilcabo/alphadevelopment/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

[Here's the webserver logs][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oawtD.png

Comment: Please share docker logs of your `webserver` container.

Comment: @KapilKhandelwal i have already attached it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly mistake, port 443 wasn't allowed on my application. I was confused because when i checked on my server, port 443 was open. Then I checked here, https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ , saying it was closed. I then found out that there's an inbound rule for AWS EC2 instance top allow port 443.

Credits here: [NGINX SSL Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845596/nginx-ssl-timeout/8995136#8995136)